# Fields of Django FormWizard are shared between users?

Tags: django, django-forms

Some time ago I found at SOV how to dynamically add fields to a FormWizard form. ( [Django WizardForm and second form will be "dynamic"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256194/django-wizardform-and-second-form-will-be-dynamic))

I did as described and everything worked flawlessly. Until 2 users start doing the same FormWizard at the same time. Then they start seeing each other values of the forms. So if user A is at form 3 and user B starts doing form 2, the user B will see the answers of form 2 from user A. In fact, since B is already at 2, it means that form 1A now contains the values from form 1B.

I've noticed somebody else also has the same exact issue, but no solution found.
[Django FormWizard Dynamically Alter form_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164303/django-formwizard-dynamically-alter-form-list)

Any ideas on how to avoid this or fix it? Is it a bug from FormWizard? Session collisions? I'm open to ditch FormWizard, does anybody know a good replacement?

I'm also open to "crappy" ways of fixing this problem, like suffixing all fields with the user ID or something like that. I would like to have this fixed ASAP.

Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django FormWizard Dynamically Alter form\_list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164303/django-formwizard-dynamically-alter-form-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://packages.python.org/django-merlin/